# django error mail: html format as debug = ture

Tags: django, email, error-handling

Is there a easy way in django to send html-formated error messages, just like they are shown in the browser when debug = True?

I would like to have the local vars for each traceback available in the error mail.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the [sentry](https://github.com/dcramer/django-sentry). It will do what you want way better than debug emails

```
sudo easy_install sentry
```

PS. I prefer to use django-sentry, an older version intended for Django only, as I'm more used to it:

```
sudo easy_install raven==0.7
sudo easy_install django-sentry
```